# what is the total no of daemons in Hadoop(0.20.2)?

Tags: hadoop

Hey I am new to Hadoop please help me to find following question.
what is the total number of daemons in Hadoop(0.20.2) and what are they.

Answer (score 0):

**Hadoop 0.20.2**

Namenode, Secondary Namenode, Datanode, Jobtracker, Tasktracker

**Hadoop 2.0 (YARN)**

Namenode, Secondary Namenode, Resource Manager, Node Manager, Datanode

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 daemons in Hadoop 0.20
It works on master and slaves node basis.
Your Namenode and Jobtracker acts as master and DataNode and Tasktracker as slaves.

1. NameNode - It contains all the information of your DataNode,access permissions, locations of your Nodes. However it does not contain the actual information of your data.
2. DataNode - It contains your actual information or data.
3. SecondaryNameNode- It takes backup of your NameNode metadata information. It takes backup every hour.
4. Jobtracker - It keeps track of the availability of your Namenode. It assigns your MapReduce job to Tasktracker(if it is available for processing). As hadoop takes process to the data and not the other way around.
5. Tasktracker - It runs the process on your DataNode machine.